# How can i let frames share resources in java

Tags: java, netbeans

i wan to let a frame to show the information queried by another frame...how can i do that... a frame already has all the information queried from database(SQL) but i dont know how to let that information appeared in another frame in netbeans

another problem is that i cant change built-in methods in netbeans to private.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    Home().Dept_Progam();
```

Dept_Program() is the frame i want to use to dislay information in Home() frame

Home () contains frame and database query.

Comment: Create a child frame

Comment: please stick to the java code conventions: methods start with lowercase: `home().deptProgram();`

Comment: Please read  [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: netbeans has already generate frame for me which i was not able to edit....like changing methods to public

Answer (score 0):

create the new frame with parameters..??

form within the main frame call the child frame(called CHILD() ) like

```
new child(String s1,String s2....);
```

Comment: umm?? a child frame is just like your normal frame.
just have multiple parameters in its constructor , so that when you call it , you can pass as much data you want !